# Need Help Assigning Correct Media Queries

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

Can someone please help me to apply the right media query on a responsive Bootstrap one page template I'm working on. 
I managed to show the toggle menu button from 240px to 640px width instead of up to 980px, but I can't manage to show the main navigation menu from from 640px to 980px. 
After 980px it displays fine again.

Here the media query I created for the toggle menu button:

```
@media (min-width: 639px) { 
.btn-navbar {
display: none;
}
}
```

And here the html for the whole header section:

```
<!-- header -->
<div class="masthead">
  <div class="stripes"></div>
  <div class="container"> 
    <!-- button for small devices-->
    <div class="row no-margin">
      <div class="span12">
        <div class="hidden-desktop"> <a class="btn btn-navbar"  data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse"><span class="icon-align-justify"></span></a></div>
        <div class="brand"> <a href="#intro"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="" /></a></div>
        <!-- navigation -->
        <div class="navbar main-nav">
          <div class="nav-collapse collapse" >
            <ul class="nav pull-right ">
              <li><a href="#intro">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#work">Intro</a></li>
              <li><a href="#services">Amulets</a></li>
              <li><a href="#blog">Gallery</a></li>
              <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end navigation --> 
  </div>
  <!-- end container --> 
</div>
<!-- end header-->
```

I tried everything I can think of but can't manage to get it right.
Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Anyway you could set this up in a jsfiddle.net for us to play around with?  It will help you get a faster and more accurate answer.

Comment: @Fernker 

jsfiddle.net didn't work, I don't know why. Did it in CODEPEN instead and here is the result: [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/DpCcB) I used the template untouched and just added the `@media (min-width: 639px) { .btn-navbar { display: none; } }` at the end of the css. Included in the code are bootstrap.css, bootstrap-responsive.css and style.css. No js. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Well you could try simply using the `!important` directive:

```
@media (min-width: 639px) {
    .btn-navbar { display: none !important; }
}
```

Granted, this is not the most elegant solution.
But your problem seems to have to do with your styles, not your markup.
It is most likely to be conflicting styles.
I think for this one, we'll have to look deep into the whole stylesheet to find the problem.

Also, note that the `.btn-navbar` link is inside a `<div>` with a `.hidden-desktop` class.

Comment: The toggle button query: `@media (min-width: 639px) { .btn-navbar { display: none; } }` is not the issue, it works as I want it too. I can't accomplish having the main navigation showing between 640px and 979px. Example: `@media (min-width: 640px) { .nav.pull-right { display: none; } }` This removes main navigation at all and leaves only the toggle menu up to 639px and if set to `display: block;` it shows the main navigation but only starting at 980px and leaves me without main navigation between 640px and 979px. How to get it showing up starting at 640px ?